# Integrate Liquibase Groovy DSL in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, liquibase

Trying to integrate like this:
**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.1.1'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    runtime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.1.1'
}
```

In Spring Boot application.properties

```
spring.liquibase.changeLog=classpath:db/changelog/changeset0002.groovy
```

Have a corresponding `changeset0002.groovy` file under `src/main/resources/db/changelog`.

While doing `gradle bootRun`, getting the following exception:

> `Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`

Answer (score 0):

It works. In my **application.properties** file, with the following setting, I got it working:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:META-INF/scripts/changeset0001.groovy
```

where the directories **META-INF/scripts** exist under **src/main/resources** of my *Gradle* project structure and **changeset0001.groovy** is a usual Groovy DSL file.